# Next.js react.refresh.runtime errors

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js14

As soon as I install `nextjs` packages with `npx create-next-app@latest` and run the developer server, the following reads in the browser console:

```bash
at eval (react-refresh-runtime.development.js:530:9)
at eval (react-refresh-runtime.development.js:542:7)
at (:3000/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-refresh/cjs/react-refresh-runtime.development.js (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/main-app.js?v=1706052645707:127:1)
at options.factory (webpack.js?v=1706052645707:710:31)
at __webpack_require__ (webpack.js?v=1706052645707:37:33)
at fn (webpack.js?v=1706052645707:365:21)
at eval (runtime.js:3:22)
at (:3000/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-refresh/runtime.js (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/main-app.js?v=1706052645707:138:1)
at options.factory (webpack.js?v=1706052645707:710:31)
at __webpack_require__ (webpack.js?v=1706052645707:37:33)
```

This is not allowing my react components to work.